# ADS Simulation: Schematic to find input impedance

Tags: diodes, impedance-matching, ads

I'm following a paper, using ADS, to find the input impedance of a shunt Schottky diode. The paper's schematic is Fig. 1, and my schematic is Fig. 2.

I could not get the same result as the paper reported. Here are their steps and my corresponding results:

1. Their method: Shortening the Impedance Matching tool, varying Pin. It was said the rectifier operates optimally when the diode's peak reverse voltage, Vr_max reaches Bv (6.4 V as in the model). They found Vr_max = 6.4 V @ Pin = 12.320 dBm (Fig. 3).
2. My results: Vr_max = peak(Vd). With Pin in the range (-5, 15), my Vr_max could not reach 6.4 V. At Pin = 12.320 dBm, my Vr_max = 4.509 V while Vout = 2.599 V (Fig.4).

Therefore Zin (input impedance) is totally different from the paper's findings. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a wide tolerance on Vbr and Infineon's is Vbr= 4V min @ 100uA  yet the typical log curve indicates 5uA at 4V with a  shift in the log curve at 2.5V then again at 3.5V

Comment: Thank you very much Tony EE. Could you please explain this in more details? Did you mean Vbr to be Bv, the breakdown voltage of the diode?

Comment: Vbr is the threshold at 100uA  similar to Vt threshold for zeners and higher is Vzt for rated at 5mA

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is a wide tolerance on Vbr and Infineon's is Vbr= 4V min @ 100uA yet the typical log curve indicates 5uA at 4V with a slight shift in the log curve at 2.5V then again at 3.5V

Your signal shows a slight saturation above 3V and almost 10% compression at 4.5V
[image]

**For [Infineon the Absolute maximum Voltage rating](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAT15-03W-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265f064ff01663896078c4e80) is Vr=4V**

Comment: Thank you very much Tony. Are you saying that although Bv is said to be 6.4V as mentioned in the paper, it is actually 4V? So, what I need to do is to find the Pin correspding to Vmax=4V instead of 6.4V, if I follow the paper's concept?

Comment: Some Paper's are not worth reading , and I haven't read this one.